# Washed out colors with HDMI

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, intel, colors

Similar questions have been asked before but so far they have not solved this problem.

On my laptop ([Dell Precision 5510](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/productdetails/precision-m5510-workstation) with hybrid graphics GPUs Intel/Nvidia) with Ubuntu 16.04 the colors are washed out when connected to external display with HDMI. This does not happen on Windows or on the laptop screen. My guess is that this is related to limited RGB color settings (16:235 instead of 0:255).

I have tried `xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"` but it did not help.

I did not find any related settings from NVIDIA X Server Settings (`nvidia-settings`)

NVIDIA Driver Version: 381.22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to use Intel GPU from `nvidia-settings` and then execute the `xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"` and then switch back to Nvidia GPU.

Note that you can get the correct output (in this case HDMI-1-1) with `xrandr` and the output may change when switching GPUs.