# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS: LiveCD (USB): Bad Image Quality Via HDMI with Sharp Television Model LC-32LB481U

Tags: live-usb, hdmi, thinkpad

When Ubuntu asks if I want to "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu", the HDMI output on the television looks OK. After clicking "Try Ubuntu", the image is extremely red.

Things Tried:

- The situation does not improve after trying to install the available updates.
- Disabling color management and toggling the TV mode switch in the Displays settings dialog.
- Reporting a bug. I got "This is not a genuine Ubuntu package" (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en) error.
- [Washed out colors with HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914225/washed-out-colors-with-hdmi?rq=1) did not help because the LiveCD does not include "nvidia-settings".

Not Attempted Yet:

Discard the television and buy a new television.

Steps to Reproduce the Problem:

1. Download the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS ISO from [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com).
2. Put it on a USB drive using Rufus.
3. Plug USB drive into a powered-off ThinkPad.
4. Press power button on ThinkPad.
5. Immediately mash the Enter key until you can ask the computer to show the Boot Options menu.
6. Tell the computer to show the Boot Options menu.
7. Tell the computer to boot from the USB drive.
8. Press Enter when Ubuntu asks how to boot.
9. Wait for the Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu screen to appear.
10. Plug the ThinkPad into a Sharp television.
11. Look at television.
12. Click "Try Ubuntu".
13. Look at television again.

System That Created the USB Drive:

- Windows 10 (Version 21H2)
- Rufus 3.21.1949

USB Drive:

- SanDisk Extreme PRO
- 128 GB
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

System That Tried To Boot Ubuntu:

- Lenovo ThinkPad P53
- Cables Tried:

  - AmazonBasics HDMI cable
  - Monoprice HDMI cable
- Sharp Television:

  - Model: LC-32LB481U
  - Software version: 11.0.0 / build 4193-13

Comment: Are you seeking support?  or trying to report a bug.  Your *support question* reads more like a bug report to me, and this isn't a bug tracker. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for details on reporting bugs, but if you have trouble with the `ubuntu-bug` tools, you can always file the report online with launchpad, then add additional details using `apport-collect` later from the impacted box (*this would appear to get around the problem picking a package somewhat as you're selecting that online with a browser yourself*).

Comment: You may have included some details for sure, but still weren't very specific. Ubuntu has many ISOs available, and 20.04.1 narrows it done some, but even then not clearly. There are desktop, server & flavors involved, plus many *daily* images that may also be treated as 20.04.1 thus the specific ISO is recorded in the format YYYYMMDD.9  (the .9 may not exist; it's added for second/third/etc extra ISOs built on the same day). Those figures can vary on ISO, eg.  20220809 is the released 20.04.1 Desktop for *amd64*, but not all released ISOs had that date, some .1 & you may mean something else too

Comment: If you're trying to report bugs, please us a bug tracker that will be seen by *developers* of Ubuntu, and not a user-support site only seen by end-users.